# global search on geojsons from geoserver

Tags: search, gis, geoserver

I want to get Features corresponding to search text based on properties present in geojsons from geoserver. Search should be performed on value of each property from properties in geojson.

There are some ways I found to filter results with use of **cql_filters** but in order to perform global search on every attribute I need to send a request to filter on a parameter.

Is there a way by which I can get all shape files matching my search text from every layer present in a workspace of geoserver.

Answer (score 0):

@Raviraj-walke Please go through the geoserver discussion forum. There is a topic that discuss this problem https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/25471393/